# Google App Engine Errno 60 Operation timed out

Tags: google-app-engine

I've an Angular application deployed on Google App Engine. I deploy it by:

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

It always worked for several months, but from the last 2-3 days I got this error:

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 24 files to Google Cloud Storage               ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) [Errno 60] Operation timed out
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.
```

Here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
default_expiration: "1s"
```

Do you have some hints?

Thanks

Comment: Anything interesting in the logs?

Comment: It looks like your client is unable to reach the server, could you try to deploy with the debug flag? `--verbosity=debug`.